# Automating this: Finding and deleting rows in several dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have several DataFrames, **AR, AL, BT** etc where I wish to delete certain rows. All of the dataframes have the **PNR** column. There are certain rows corresponding to some **PNR** values I wish to delete in all these dataframes, I find them this way:

```py
In [28]:

AR['PNR'].value_counts() > 1
Out[28]:
570604         True
570213         True
5804030210     True
5703301118    False
5509100177    False
5808100191    False
4108271224    False
5603050120    False
5112271498    False
etc...
```

So here I wish to delete all rows in every dataframe where **PNR** is 570604, 570213, or 5804030210.

My stupid method is to then do this:

```
AR = AR[AR.PNR != 570604]
AR = AR[AR.PNR != 570213]
etc
BT = BT[BT.PNR != 5804030210]
```

Any suggestions of a nicer way to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
AR = AR[~AR.PNR.isin(bad_values)]
```

You can get that list of bad values a couple of ways.

I haven't tested this, but my first attempt would be something like this:

```
vc = AR.PNR.value_counts()
bad_values = vc[vc > 1].index.tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I run "AR.PNR[AR.PNR.value_counts() > 1]" I get: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided